# MySQL full join (union) with ambiguous column names

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, union

I'm quite disappointed by the fact that MySQL still doesn't support FULL JOIN after so many years (why anyway?) and that i have to use UNION as workaround. Said that i'm having problems with the following query. I have two tables as example:

**Computers**

```
id   userid   owner   cpu   
1    1        Jack    3.4
2    1        Jack    3.4
3    2        Sara    3.0
```

**Monitors**

```
id   userid   owner   inch  
1    1        Jack    22    
2    1        Jack    22    
3    3        Mark    17    
4    4        Luke    32
```

Basically i have a list of computers with specifications that have been assigned to an owner. Similarly i have a list of monitors with specifications and each monitor assigned to an owner. I want to combine these two tables by owner into this result:

```
id   userid   owner   cpu   id   userid   owner   inch  
1    1        Jack    3.4   1    1        Jack    22
2    1        Jack    3.4   2    1        Jack    22
3    2        Sara    3.0   null null     null    null 
null null     null    null  3    3        Mark    17
null null     null    null  4    4        Luke    32
```

I can successfully get the result above with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM computers AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN monitors AS o on a.owner = o.owner
UNION
SELECT * FROM computers AS a
RIGHT OUTER JOIN monitors AS o on a.owner = o.owner
```

The problems are:

1. I **don't want** to use jolly character in my query not only because it's not efficient but also because i only need some specific columns an not all
2. Both table have ambiguous column names (id, userid, owner) so for example it seems that i can't ORDER BY owner. I know that i should use aliases but i don't understand how to implement it
3. I have to use WHERE statement but again i don't understand how to implement it because of ambiguous column names

Now to summarize what i said in a pseudo-query i would:

> SELECT id AS a_id, userid AS a_userid, owner AS a_owner **but NOT
>   cpu** FROM computers WHERE cpu = 3.4

UNION and JOIN by owner:

> SELECT id AS b_id, userid AS b_userid, owner AS b_owner, inch AS b_inch FROM monitors WHERE inch = 22

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I wonder how much of this is just a fictitious example and how much is not. The database design is bad, having both user id and name repeated in every record. Then you combine all computers and monitors a person owns. What for? To see all the interesting possible combinations? With the query given you wouldn't get two Jack records but four. As to ambiguous column names: They need a qualifier. You already use this in a.owner = o.owner. So where is the problem?

Comment: As i have already said mine is just an example. Trust me when i say you that there's a point in a having a structure like this. If you think that design is bad then you have to blame with http://www.whmcs.com/. Anyway belive me. The design is absolutely good and functional. The point here is not debating on how bad/good the design is but how to make a FULL JOIN.

Comment: Okay. Sometimes such side remarks are helpful. I didn't mean to attack :-) I've posted an answer. Hope it answers all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to emulate the `full outer join` is to get the full list of values (`owner`s in your case) using a subquery.  Then use `left outer join` to bring in the other values.  Based on what you describe:

```
select c.id as c_id, c.userid as c_userid, o.owner as owner,
       m.id as m_id, m.user_id as m_userid, m.inch
from (select owner from computers union
      select owner from monitors
     ) o left outer join
     computers c
     on o.owner = c.owner left outer join
     monitors m
     on o.owner = m.owner;
```

However, the query that you mention will not generate these results.  It would generate four results for "Jack".

EDIT:

I suspect that you want to match on `owner`, `id`, and `user_id`:

```
select c.id as c_id, c.userid as c_userid, o.owner as owner,
       m.id as m_id, m.user_id as m_userid, m.inch
from (select owner, id, userid from computers union
      select owner, id, userid from monitors
     ) o left outer join
     computers c
     on o.owner = c.owner and o.userid = c.userid and o.id = c.id left outer join
     monitors m
     on o.owner = m.owner and o.userid = m.userid and o.id = m.id;
```

Comment: Correct. My query is not returning what i said. I need few minutes to "refresh" my mind and understand your approach.

Comment: Yes, the second query is what i was looking for. It works. Now i need some minutes to fully understand how does it work and also to understand where/how i can inject my **WHERE c_cpu = 3.4 AND m_inch = 22** plus **ORDER BY c_id** (i'm still using pseudo-query of course)

Comment: @user1274113 . . . You should ask another question.  Extended questions and answers in the comments section is frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full outer join on cpu = 3.4 and Inch = 22. First get all computers and join monitors, then get all monitors and join computers. Main table criteria is in the WHERE clause, outer join criteria is in the ON clause.

```
SELECT 
    a.userid, a.owner, a.id as computer_id, o.id as monitor_id, o.inch
FROM  
    computers AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    monitors AS o ON a.owner = o.owner 
                  AND a.userid = o.userid 
                  AND o.inch = 22
WHERE 
    a.cpu = 3.4

UNION

SELECT 
    o.userid, o.owner, a.id as computer_id, o.id as monitor_id, o.inch
FROM 
    monitors AS o
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    computers AS a ON a.owner = o.owner 
                   AND a.userid = o.userid 
                   AND a.cpu = 3.4
WHERE 
    o.inch = 22;
```

This can be sped up, however, by only adding those records that the first select doesn't find, i.e. the monitors that have no matching computer. Then you can use UNION ALL instead of UNION which saves the dbms a lot of work. You just pick up a non-nullable column of the outer joined table. When it is NULL then the record is outer joined.

```
SELECT a.userid, a.owner, a.id as computer_id, o.id as monitor_id, o.inch
FROM computers AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN monitors AS o 
  ON a.owner = o.owner and a.userid = o.userid and o.inch = 22
WHERE a.cpu = 3.4
UNION ALL
SELECT o.userid, o.owner, a.id as computer_id, o.id as monitor_id, o.inch
FROM monitors AS o
LEFT OUTER JOIN computers AS a
  ON a.owner = o.owner and a.userid = o.userid and a.cpu = 3.4
WHERE o.inch = 22 and o.owner is null;
```